How to create LINQ, that selects lists from list of lists that they contain all elements of any list from other list of lists?
I could not find or figure out similar LINQ example.
For the example, I have 2 lists:
List<List<string>> cases = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "a", "c", "b", "w", "z" },
    new List<string>() { "s", "c", "b", "w", "z" },
    new List<string>() { "t", "c", "b", "w", "z" },
    new List<string>() { "u", "c", "b", "w", "z" }, //<- this one should be picked up
};

and
List<List<string>> pairs = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "a", "r" },
    new List<string>() { "a", "f" },
    new List<string>() { "u", "f" },
    new List<string>() { "u", "z" }, //<- these are contained
};

I need to get cases that contains all elements of ANY of pairs. How to do it with LINQ?
My best try is:
var res = pairs.Where(x => cases.All(y => x.All(z => y.IndexOf(z) >= 0))).ToList();

But gives no results :/

This gives you your desired result:
var res = cases.Where(caseList => pairs.Any(pairList => pairList.All(caseList.Contains))).ToList();

Explanation:

you want to find matches in cases not in pairs, so use Where on that
you want all cases that contain all strings of any list in pairs, that's the query above ;)

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XSECpV

Actually that makes the work, thank you!
